# wsgi script's environment is isolated hosted on httpd, CentOS 7

Tags: python, httpd, centos7, wsgi

I'm hosting a simple **wsgi application** on **httpd** over **CentOS 7** using `mod_wsgi` and trying to remove the isolation illustrated below.

### The `wsgi` app,

The following script is my `wsgi` application.

- it creates a file called `/tmp/test-wsgi.txt`
- enumerates the content of `/tmp` as a simple json list

*code:*

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'application/json')]
    start_response(status, headers)

    with open('/tmp/test-wsgi.txt', 'w+') as w:
        w.write('hello world')

    files = os.listdir('/tmp')
    return json.dumps(files)
```

When i'm accessing my web application i'm getting the following response

```
["test-wsgi.txt"]
```

**Great so far!**

---

### However,

Connected to the same hosting server as root,

I've opened a shell and executed `cat /tmp/test-wsgi.txt`

[image]

From playing around with it, seems that any filesystem operation (enumeration/creation/socket access) inside my wsgi script is *"environmently isolated"* (like chroot jail). the strange thing is i haven't configured any of that type of isolation.

---

### httpd config

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/my-app.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /opt/my-app/

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/my-app/apache/wsgi.py

<Directory /opt/my-app/apache>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
...

User apache
Group apache

...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Security Feature, [PrivateTmp](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/)

It's a security feature called [PrivateTmp](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/), configured by default with `httpd` systemd service.

#### How to disable it?

Edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service` and **remove** the following line:

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

Then run the following commands,

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service httpd restart
```